# spaceless block inside autoescape throws SyntaxException in Twig 3.*

Tags: php, twig

Just updated from Twig `2.*` to Twig `3.*`

Most of my templates are wrapped in the `{% autoescape %} ... {% endautoescape %}` block

And some templates have `{% spaceless %} ... {% endspaceless %}` block inside.

In final it looks like this:

```
{% autoescape %}
  ...
  {% spaceless %}
    ...
  {% endspaceless %}
  ...
{% endautoescape %}
```

And now (after the update to `3.*`) I get `SyntaxException` from Twig.

How should these block be rewritten/supported?

Why such construction is no longer supported by the Twig?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected "spaceless" tag (expecting closing tag for the "autoescape" tag defined near line 2). in

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the [`apply`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/apply.html) tag now, e.g.

```html
{% apply spaceless %}
 ...
{% endapply %}
```

[reference](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/spaceless.html)

---

The reason is for this construction is to have a consistent codebase as you now can "apply" filter(s) to chunk of texts, e.g.

```
{% apply upper %}
    This {{ text }} becomes uppercase
{% endapply %}
```

whereas you needed to concat it in the past and add parentheses

`{{ ('This '~text~' becomes uppercase')|upper }}`

---

**TLDR** To be consistent they've decided to remove the *tag* spaceless and to introduce the *filter* spaceless

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

Answer (score 0):

Similar Error here, however after fixing one of the file (by adding apply and endapply) error messages persists.

I love the [Mediteran theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediteran) for my Admin, which worked fine with Drupal 9. However, after upgrading to Drupal 10, I got this error.

**Error:**

```
 ---- -------------- drush ws-------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Type     Severity   Message
 ---- -------------- -------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  php      Error      Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected "spaceless" tag (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag defined near line 27). in Twig\Parser->subparse() (line 30 of path/to/themes
  php      Error      Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected "spaceless" tag (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag defined near line 27). in Twig\Parser->subparse() (line 30 of path/to/themes
  php      Error      Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected "spaceless" tag (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag defined near line 27). in Twig\Parser->subparse() (line 30 of path/to/themes
 php      Error      Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected "spaceless" tag (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag defined near line 27). in Twig\Parser->subparse() (line 30 of path/to/themes
```

**Solution:**

Is to search for ‘`spaceless`’  in the template directory. `/themes/contrib/mediteran/templates`

To search for a specific text in all files within a directory and replace it with something else, you can use the `find` command in combination with `grep` and `sed`. And you can add the `-name` option to the find command.

**Steps I followed:**

```
grep -rn --include="*.twig" "spaceless" path/to/mediteran/templates
```

**Output:**

```
path/to/mediteran/templates/form/dropbutton-wrapper.html.twig:13:  {% spaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/form/dropbutton-wrapper.html.twig:19:  {% endspaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/form/select.html.twig:13:{% apply spaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/admin/ckeditor-settings-toolbar.html.twig:14:{% spaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/admin/ckeditor-settings-toolbar.html.twig:73:{% endspaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/field/link-formatter-link-separate.html.twig:15:{% spaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/field/link-formatter-link-separate.html.twig:22:{% endspaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/navigation/toolbar.html.twig:30:        {% spaceless %}
path/to/mediteran/templates/navigation/toolbar.html.twig:41:        {% endspaceless %}
```

So now we know where the issue is, so we find (`spaceless`) and replace all with (`apply spaceless`).

```
find path/to/mediteran/templates -type f -name "*.twig" -exec grep -l "spaceless" {} \; -exec sed -i 's/spaceless/apply spaceless/g' {} \;
```

**Note the above command could change** `endspaceless` to `endapply spaceless`

So we need to run another command to change `endapply spaceless` to `endapply`.

```
find path/to/mediteran/templates -type f -name "*.twig" -exec grep -l "endapply spaceless" {} \; -exec sed -i 's/endapply spaceless/endapply/g' {} \;
```

These same steps can be employed to fix other deprecated tag error messages, should they appear in more than one instance.